# saving the values in database of sd card in android

Tags: android

I am developing a small android application in which I have to save the values in database.

How should I pursue?

Comment: Tell us what research have you've already done? For instance, when I google "android database" the first three hits are: 1. [android.database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html) 2.  [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), and [android.database.sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html). The fourth one on cursors is also good. These are all good starting points. Also try searches for "android database example" and "android database tutorial".

Comment: I want to save using shared preference,,,

Comment: If you want to save it using shared preferences [Check this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use database or shared preferences for your applications? If you are looking for shared preferences, the following is a piece of code that demonstrates how to store and retrieve a username and password.

```
//Saving the username and password

editor = getSharedPreferences("SampleApps", 0).edit();  
editor.putString("userName", "David");  
editor.putString("password", "Bravo");  
editor.commit();

//Retrieving username and password

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SampleApps", 1);  
String userName=sharedPreferences.getString("userName", null);  
String password=sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you can use both Shared preferences and database to save the data permanently in the device.
By using Shared preferences, the data are saved in XML format. You can find the data in /data/data/yourPackage/shared_prefs. It is a simple format recommended to have variables.

For more complicated structure, you should use the database that comes with Android, which is SQlite. You can find the database in /data/data/yourPackage/databases SQL sentences could be used to create tables and add values. For easier use, an adapter is recommended.

For more information, there is very good tutorial in the Android official page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html